# Json.net serialize boolean as int when running on production server but as true/false on development machine

Tags: json.net

On development machine, json.net boolean serialization give me true or false which is the good behavior for my purpose.
But when I run on a production server (windows server 2008 with .NET 4.0), the serialization give me 0 or 1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference was that I was running on my development machine in 32bits mode and my production server was in 64bits.
Switch in 32bits on my production server solve the problem !